# Set parameters if its ajax request?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have this query that i call with ajax request:

```
   $query->whereHas($key,function($q) use($option){
                       $q->whereIn('name', $option);


});
```

In option i get data like this:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => "Selling"
  1 => "Rent"
]
```

Now on infinite scroll im calling same this query with ajax

```
  path: function(pindex) {
          console.log('RESULT PARAMS',resultUrlParams);
            return "/search/filter?"+ resultUrlParams +"&page=" + pindex;
        }
```

And my url is :

```
publishing_types=Selling,Rent&priceFrom=0&priceTo=300000&areaFrom=0&areaTo=300000
```

My question is how can i handle now this `publishing_types` to work with query above, because now im getting an error.Its array on first and now its looks like this. Any suggestion? Maybe i need to pass array for publishing_types in url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `publishing_types` in the URL to:

```
...publishing_types[]=Selling&publishing_types[]=Rent...
```